# Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^∞ (-1)^n(n)/(n+2)$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

First I tried using the ratio test but that did not work because it was inconclusive. I think I have to use the alternating series test. If I can prove that the underlying sequence diverges then I can then say that the series diverges, however I do not know where to begin to show that the sequence $(-1)^n(n)/(n+2)$ diverges. Any tips on what methods to use would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *nth-term test* says that if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\neq 0$ or this limits does not exist, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges. In your case one can factor out $n$ of the absolute value and see that  $$\frac{n}{n+2}=\frac{1}{1+2/n}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1\neq 0.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n+2}$$
diverges and thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+2}$$
as well (in accordance to the alternating series test).

Comment: Why is n/(n+2) the absolute value?

Comment: never mind the absolute value of (-1)^n is 1 :)

Answer (score 3):

A necessary condition for a series to converge is that the terms converge to zero. Clearly $\frac{-1^n(n)}{n+2}$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: I can tell by looking at it that it does not converge to 0, but how would you show that mathematically?

Comment: its absolute value is always larger than $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @Garrett $$\frac{n}{n+2}=\frac{1}{1+2/n}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1\neq 0$$

Comment: @Christian I understand that, but what about the (-1)^n, why does that not matter?

Comment: A sequence converges to zero if and only if its absolute value converges to zero.

Comment: Here is a proof it does not converge to zero: Notice $|-1^n\frac{n}{n+2}-0|=|\frac{n}{n+2}|\geq\frac{1}{3}$. So if we take $\epsilon=3$ there is no $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value of the summand does not tend to 0, hence series diverges

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "summand"?

Comment: I mean $|a_n|$, it does not tend to 0